# In vs code emulator is not working live when i am changing something in my app i have to hot reload it again and again

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

In vs code emulator is not working live when i am changing something in my app i have to hot reload it again and again
I watched a tutorial his emulator was working live he was not hot reloading it again and again

How my emulator can work like that

Comment: in vs code if you make any change you have to save the code manually then it reflect the changes in emulator clicking on hot reload button does't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main file you will see `Run` above your main() function,
click on it to run it , you can also launch it by `Ctrl + F5`
This way when you save your file it will automatically update